# assign sequential number for 1st column of data and start from 1 when it reaches a blank line. using awk or/and sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a big data file consist of blocks of xy data, blocks are separated by a blank line. now I want to change all x to a set of sequential number, and start from 1 for next block. number of rows within each block could be different.

input:

```
165168 14653  
5131655 51365  
155615 1356  

13651625 13651  
12 51  
55165 51656 

64 64  
651456 546546
```

desired output:

```
1 14653  
2 51365  
3 1356  

1 13651  
2 51  
3 51656  

1 64  
2 546546
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use:

```
$ awk '!NF{i=0; print; next} {print ++i, $2}' file
1 14653
2 51365
3 1356

1 13651
2 51
3 51656

1 64
2 546546
```

#### Explanation

It is a matter of keeping a counter `i` and resetting it appropriately.

- `!NF{i=0; print; next}` if there are no fields, that is, if the line is empty, print an empty line and reset the counter.
- `{print ++i, $2}` otherwise, increment the counter and print it together with the 2nd field.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe even

```
awk '!NF { n=NR } NF { $1=NR-n } 1' file
```

So on an empty line, we set `n` to the current line number. On nonempty lines, we change the first field to the current line number minus `n`. Print all lines.

Comment: this is a nice one too! +1

Comment: wait, you mean `$1=NR-n`, it should be a typo in your code. since in your explanation you explained it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, fixed!